# Job task don't execute

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I'm using quartz on my Java Web application and I have a weird problem. I'm thinking the quartz its executing but don't "run" the Job task:

my configuration files:

quartz-job.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<quartz xmlns="http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/JobSchedulingData"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" overwrite-existing-jobs="true">  
     <job>  
          <job-detail>  
               <name>MyJob</name>  
               <group>DEFAULT</group>  
               <description>####</description>  
               <job-class>com.myQuartz.MyJob</job-class>  
          </job-detail>  
          <trigger>  
               <cron>  
                    <name>MyTrigger</name>  
                    <group>DEFAULT</group>  
                    <job-name>MyJob</job-name>  
                    <job-group>DEFAULT</job-group>  
                    <cron-expression>0 0/5 * * * ?</cron-expression>
               </cron>  
          </trigger>  
     </job>  
</quartz>`
```

quartz.properties:

```
#===============================================================  
#Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
#===============================================================  
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = QuartzScheduler  
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO  

#===============================================================  
#Configure ThreadPool  
#===============================================================  
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount =  3  
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5  
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool  

#===============================================================  
#Configure JobStore  
#===============================================================  
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore  

#===============================================================  
#Configure Plugins  
#===============================================================  
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.JobInitializationPlugin  
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.overWriteExistingJobs = true  
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = false  
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 10  
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.validating=false  
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileName =quartz-jobs.xml
```

web.xml (just add this):

```
`<context-param>  
   <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>  
 <param-value>/src/quartz.properties</param-value> 
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
<param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
<param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
<param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
<param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
<param-name>quartz:start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
   <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param> 
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
 </listener>`
```

MyJob.java:

```
package com.myJob;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;

public class MyJob implements Job  {

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context){

      try{
          System.out.println("Quartz working!");
      } catch (Exception ex){
      System.out.println("not working");
     }
   }
}
```

CONSOLE:

Quartz Initializer Servlet loaded, initializing Scheduler...

Scheduler has been started...

Storing the Quartz Scheduler Factory in the servlet context at key: org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.KEY

Quartz Scheduler successful shutdown.

Thx

Comment: are you waiting for 5 minutes before shutting down application?

Answer (score 0):

My question is why aren't you using Spring's built in quartz support?  You can get rid of the quartz-job.xml and all the web.xml configuration and replace it with a few lines of xml...

```
<bean id="scheduler"
     class="org.springframework.scheduling.quarexecutetz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
     p:triggers-ref="triggers" p:autoStartup="true" p:trigger-ref="triggers"
     p:configLocation="classpath:/quartz.properties" />

<util:list id="triggers">
     <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean" 
         p:jobDetail-ref="myJobDetail" p:cronExpression="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</util:list>

<bean id="myJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean"
    p:targetObject-ref="myJob" p:targetMethod="execute" />

<bean id="myJob" class="com.myjob.MyJob"...
```

Using Spring's quartz support, your jobs can be simple POJOs managed by Spring, injected with the beans you need.  You will not need to mess with `JobExecutionContext`, in fact your code will be completely decoupled from quartz.

**Edit:**  The xml above is an example of an `applicationContext`, the core configuration of a spring application.  In a web application, you include a `context-param` in your web.xml to load Spring...

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I suggest you do some more reading of the excellent [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/), because if you don't know these basics you are not using Spring.

Comment: but how can I use this method to resolve my problem? I mean, I need generate another xml file or include this code on my quartz-job.xml

Comment: I thought you were using Spring (this question is tagged with it).  Showing you how to use spring is beyond the scope of your question.  My apologies, you can ignore my answer.

Comment: I'm thinking, to Quartz start's when the application is running, so I need include on the web.xml (to start with the TomCat) I'm right?

Comment: Have something wrong on the scheduler? and I need edit something on the header??

Comment: I mean on the beans (this is the beans on my context)  `<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">`

Comment: Edit your question to add the code / configuration.  The comment is unreadable.  Add your full spring and web.xml config.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Quartz? Spring has convenient [@Scheduled](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled) annotation:

```
@Service
class JobBean {

    @Scheduled(cron="0 0/5 * * * *")
    public void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an XML based [task execution](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-namespace-scheduled-tasks):

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">        
    <task:scheduled ref="jobBean" method="doSomething" cron="0 0/5 * * * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

Don't forget to add `@EnableScheduling` (or use the `<task>` name space) to [configure](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#secheduling-enable-annotation-support) the scheduler.